# docker login fails on gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-machine

Im trying to deploy a django app using the gitlab ci and using docker for the same .

My deploy.sh file:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@$EC2_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS << 'ENDSSH'
  cd /home/ec2-user/app
  export $(cat .env | xargs)
  docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  docker pull $IMAGE:web
  docker pull $IMAGE:nginx
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
ENDSSH
```

.yml:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod +x ./deploy.sh
    - scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml ec2-user@$EC2_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/home/ec2-user/app
    - bash ./deploy.sh
```

I have a running instance on AWS EC2..

Error :

```
Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)


 Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have tried to change dns by editing /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "dns": ["192.168.4.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}

sudo service docker restart
```

But no changes!

Answer (score 0):

```
 DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8"
```

inside /etc/default/docker fixed the issue